# 日本語に違和感: ユーザープロフィール画面の「私のログイン」

Tags: 討議, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「私のログイン」だと何のことだか良くわかりません。「ログイン設定」とか「ログイン情報」とかが良いと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ログイン設定」に更新しました。次回のビルドに適用します。